Bootstrap responsive doesn't work and not recognized in devtools
I'm working on a project with Laravel Mix, Vue.js and Bootstrap 5.3
About laravel mix:
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
const path = require('path');

require("mix-env-file");
require("laravel-mix-workbox");

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .version()
   .vue()
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sourceMaps()

About app.scss
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap";
... custom things

Vue.js element
<div class="card unselectable" style="overflow: hidden;" v-if="ux.viewFilters">
    <div class="p-2">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-sm-column flex-row gap-2">

The problem is that bootstrap doesn't recognize the responsive element (flex-sm-column), neither in the devtools, but I can see it in the app.css created by laravel mix

Based on the provided details it seems like you are importing incorrectly, instead do the following:
Replace:
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap";

With
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

Since you have saas setup.

Same issue, and something happens with the configuration, 'cause primary colors become from yellow to blue... by the way I have to fix urgently the responsive part and your suggestion unfortunately doesn't work

I solved. The problem was that I pretended to use flex-sm-* for mobile device, misunderstanding the functionality of it. Everything's working properly.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
